# How to get row names of a data frome from row index values in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame named as dat. I have the row indices in a numeric vector named maxIndex.numeric. I want to retrieve all the row names from dat corresponding to the values in the maxIndex.numeric vector. I tried the following, but it errors out as shown below:

> rownames(subset(dat, x == maxIndex.numeric))

character(0)
Warning message:
In x == maxIndex.numeric :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Thanks

Comment: not sure if i got it right...an reproducible example would be nice, but have you tried `rownames(dat)[c(maxIndex.numeric)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
rownames(dat)[maxIndex.numeric]
```